# Forth to the past - qsort

Tags: quick-sort, shuffle, forth

To make a long story short, I must revive my Forth. It is rusty; last time I did anything serious in Forth was 30 years ago (man, I am old). As an exercise, I translated an STL-like implementation of `qsort`. It works (if you want to test it, install [gforth](https://www.gnu.org/software/gforth/)). It performs well comparing to SDCC-compiled native C (I don't have Keil license). I know where my bottlenecks are.

I am mostly interested in how readable the code is; how much did I sin against Forth spirit; if there are modern Forth coding conventions, how does this code fare.

```
-1 cells constant -cell
: cell- -cell + ;

: xchg ( a0 a1 -- ) 2dup @ >r @ swap ! r> swap ! ;

: unguarded_linear_insert ( last val -- )
    >r
    begin cell- dup @ dup r@ > while over cell+ ! repeat
    drop r> swap cell+ !
;

: unguarded_insertion_sort ( first last -- )
    >r
    begin dup r@ <> while dup dup @ unguarded_linear_insert cell+ repeat
    drop rdrop
;

: linear_insert ( first last val -- )
    >r over @ r@ swap <
    if
        begin 2dup <> while cell- dup @ over cell+ ! repeat
        drop r> swap !
    else
        r> unguarded_linear_insert drop
    then
;

: insertion_sort ( first last -- )
    2dup <>
    if
        >r
        dup begin cell+ dup r@ <> while 2dup dup @ linear_insert repeat
        rdrop
    then
    2drop
;


: unguarded_partition ( l f p -- cut )
    >r swap cell-
    begin dup @ r@ > while cell- repeat swap
    begin dup @ r@ < while cell+ repeat swap
    begin 2dup < while
        2dup xchg cell- swap cell+ swap
        begin dup @ r@ > while cell- repeat swap
        begin dup @ r@ < while cell+ repeat swap
    repeat
    swap drop begin dup @ r@ < while cell+ repeat
    rdrop
;

: median_of_3 ( n0 n1 n2 -- n )
    >r 2dup > if swap then
    r> 2dup > if swap then drop
       2dup < if swap then drop
;

: pivot ( l f len -- l f p )
    2 / -cell and over +          ( l f m )
    @ >r over cell- @ over @ r>
    median_of_3
;

: quicksort_loop ( l f t -- )
    begin dup >r -rot 2dup - dup r@ > while
        pivot
        >r 2dup r> unguarded_partition
        >r 2dup + r@ swap r> 2 * < if
            rot over r> recurse swap else
            dup -rot swap r> recurse then
        rot
    repeat
    rdrop 2drop 2drop
;

: quicksort ( l f )
    2dup 2 cells quicksort_loop
    dup 2 cells + dup -rot insertion_sort
    swap unguarded_insertion_sort
;

\ Testing and benchmarking

include random.fs
0 random

: shuffle ( n a -- )
    >r dup
    begin ?dup while 1- 2dup cells r@ + swap rnd swap mod cells r@ + xchg repeat
    rdrop 2drop
;

: fill-i ( n a -- )
    >r
    begin ?dup while 1- dup dup cells r@ + ! repeat
    rdrop
;

: fill-ir ( n a )
    begin 2dup ! cell+ swap 1- ?dup while swap repeat drop
;

1024 1024 * constant total-size
variable data total-size cells allocate throw data !
total-size data @ fill-i
total-size data @ shuffle
variable ssrt total-size cells allocate throw ssrt !

: exetime  utime 2>r quicksort execute  utime 2r> d- ." dtime " . cr ;

variable size 16 size !
variable logs  4 logs !

: run ( fp )
    >r
    begin total-size size @ >= while
        data @ ssrt @ size @ cells move
        ssrt @ size @ cells + ssrt @
        size @ . cr
        .s cr
        r@ hex. cr
        r@ exetime
        size @ . size @ m*/
        size @ 2 * size !
    repeat
    rdrop
;

' quicksort run
bye
```

Answer (score 2):

I see some things that could be improved with this code.

### Fix `exetime`

The `exetime` word is defined like this:

```
: exetime  utime 2>r quicksort execute  utime 2r> d- ." dtime " . cr ;
```

There are a number of problems with that.  First, the formatting is not very good.  I'd prefer to see a stack comment, for example.  Second, this should probably take a parameter so that any word can be timed (this appears to be the intent from `run`).  Third, that last `.` should be `d.` to display the entire delta time rather than just half of it.

```
: exetime  ( fp -- ) 
   utime 2>r  execute  utime 2r> d- ." dtime " d. cr 
;
```

### Use smaller words

Again using `exetime` as an example, there are actually two things done by the word as defined.  The first is that it calculates a delta time, and the second is that it prints that time.  I'd make those separate words.

### Follow Forth convention

It's common to use prefixes to simplify code.  For example, everywhere `ssrt` is used, it's followed by `@`.  For that reason, I'd define and use word like these:

```
: @ssrt ssrt @ ;
: @size size @ ;
: !size size ! ;
```

### Define and use common idioms

A number of cases in the code there is a sequence like this: `size @ .` but there is a common idiom for that and it's built in to many Forth implementations.  If it's not, it's easy to define:

```
: ?  ( a -- )   @ . ;
```

It would be used like this:  `size ?`.  Alternatively, one could use the prefix idiom which is associated with a particular value:

```
: ?size  ( -- )   size @ . ;
```

### Eliminate unused variables

The `logs` variable is defined but never used.  This needlessly clutters the code.

### Simplify control structure

Instead of using `begin .. while .. repeat`, it's often the case that one can use `begin .. until` instead and simplify the code.  Using the refactored smaller words as suggested above, here's what `run` looks like now:

```
: run ( fp )
    >r
    begin 
        copy-array
        array-limits r@ exetime
        ." size " ?size ." dtime " d. cr
    size2x total-size > until
    rdrop
;
```

These are the refactored words:

```
: exetime  ( fp -- ) utime 2>r execute utime 2r> d- ;
: copy-array ( -- ) data @ ssrt @ size @ cells move ;
: array-limits ( -- alo ahi ) ssrt @ dup size @ cells + swap ;
: @size ( -- n ) size @ ;
: ?size ( -- ) @size . ;
: size2x ( -- n ) size @ 2 * dup size ! ;
```

### Make sure comments don't lie

The `shuffle` word starts like this:

```
: shuffle ( n a -- )
```

However, that's not correct.  It should instead be:

```
: shuffle ( n1 n2 a -- )
```

### Use refactoring to improve speed

The code currently contains this:

```
: median_of_3 ( n0 n1 n2 -- n )
    >r 2dup > if swap then
    r> 2dup > if swap then drop
       2dup < if swap then drop
;
```

However, in addition to being somewhat opaque, it's not as fast as it could be.  Refactoring into smaller chunks improves both readability and speed:

```
\ arrange top two stack values to assure n0 <= n1
: lohi ( n0 n1 -- n0 n1 ) 2dup > if swap then ;
\ arrange top three stack values to assure n0 <= n1 <= n2
: 3sort ( n0 n1 n2 -- n0 n1 n2 ) lohi >r lohi r> lohi ;
\ extract median value from top 3 items on stack
: median_of_3 ( n0 n1 n2 -- n1 ) 3sort drop nip ;
```

### Be aware of non-standard extensions

The code uses the non-standard extensions:

```
 rdrop -rot utime
```

It is not hard to write replacements for the first two if needed:

```
: rdrop r> drop ;
: -rot rot rot ;
```

Since `utime` is only used in the test code, perhaps it's not as critical.  There is no standard replacement.